# MySQL cursor always exits out of loop

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, cursors

The cursor query and `select value` query returns rows if I run it in `mysql` but when in a cursor it always exits out of loop.

Anything wrong here?

I've added "BEFORE LOOP", "EXIT" and "IN LOOP" so it prints where it is but it always starts with `BEFORE LOOP` and then ends with `EXIT`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getTotal()
BEGIN

DECLARE HOSTID INTEGER;
DECLARE cITEMID INT;
declare finished bool default false;
DECLARE Total INT;
declare cur1 cursor for SELECT itemid  FROM items WHERE hostid = 10579;
declare continue handler for not found set finished = true;

open cur1;
   loop_1: loop
        fetch cur1 into cITEMID;
        SELECT "BEFORE LOOP";
        if finished then
            SELECT "EXIT";
            leave loop_1;
        end if;
        SELECT "IN LOOP";
-- Test query
      SELECT value from history_uint WHERE itemid = cITEMID ORDER BY itemid DESC LIMIT 1;

-- Final select query will look like this.
-- SET @Total := @Total + (SELECT value from history_uint WHERE itemid = cITEMID ORDER BY itemid DESC LIMIT 1);
-- SELECT @Total;

  end loop;
close cur1;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Queries:

```
SELECT itemid  FROM items WHERE hostid = 10579;
| itemid |
| 12345  |
| 12346  |
| 12347  |

SELECT value from history_uint WHERE itemid = 12345 ORDER BY itemid DESC LIMIT 1;
| value | 
| 1     |


SELECT * from history_uint;

| itemid | value | clock (unixtimestamp) |
| 12345  | 13     | 4364564654654        |
| 12346  | 1      | 4364564654657        |
| 12347  | 16     | 4364564654654        |
| 12345  | 13     | 4364564654756        |
| 12346  | 2      | 4364564654753        |
| 12347  | 15     | 4364564654756        |
```

Note: The clock column value is just made up.

Comment: It looks ok to me, could you alos post your tables with data, at least with the minimum of columns to check your problem?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: This does not make sense:  `WHERE itemid = 12345 ORDER BY itemid` -- You have the value (12345), so why do you need the `ORDER BY`, much less the `LIMIT`??

Comment: And...  If this is a "groupwise-max" problem, then there are solutions that don't need cursors.

Comment: I figured out the issue btw. It is due to variable `HOSTID` and `declare cur1 ..` has  a column named hostid. It seems we can't have variable names same as column names in the query and due to that `handler not found` gets called. Changing the `HOSTID` variable to `_HOSTID` resolved the issue.

Comment: Also to explain: The table `history_uin`t has 3 columns, itemid, value, clock. Only the  clock column (unixtimestamp) is unique. So there can be multiple same itemid and value except clock. And every 60 seconds the table gets updated with new clock value. In order for me to get only the latest value for itemid I need to `DESC LIMIT 1` because I can't use clock to filter (where clock >= unixtimestamp(now) - interval 60 second) since it can produce multiple result or sometimes none. But I always wanted at least one result for each itemd id.

Comment: Anyway managed to get this working using Stored procedure with `Prepare STMT`.

Comment: updated the question to show `select * from history_uint`. Anyway I've  managed to get this working using Stored procedure with Prepare STMT

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.

Variable should not be the same as any column in the query.

```
DECLARE HOSTID INT;

declare cur1 cursor for SELECT itemid  FROM items WHERE hostid = 10579;
```

Since the `cur1` query has a column named `hostid` it will trigger the `not found` continue handler which sets `finished` variable to `true`.

Not only it triggers continue handler but in some cases it can produce syntax error. Source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60988686/13109839

Solution rename the `HOSTID` variable to `_HOSTID`.

```
DECLARE _HOSTID INT;
```